# How do I get list values from the function? (python)

Tags: python, function

I have 2 separate files in python. In one file, I have this code with a class 'game':

```
def getPosition(self,score):
    position = [((3,1), 'Good'),((1,2), 'Bad')]
    return position
```

Then, in a second file, I have a function which takes in this class 'game' under which function 'getPosition' exists:

```
def calculateNextStep(game):
    actions = []
    actions.append(game.getPosition[0])
    return actions
```

I just want to append the list value at position 0 of getPosition into actions but getting this error:

```
line 95, in calculateNextStep
  actions.append(game.getPosition[0])          
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I clearly don't understand some crucial parts of Python. I have tried to research on my on but I am completely lost and have several theories now.

Comment: Please show the whole stack trace of the error.

Comment: Are you sure you posted your actual code?  That looks like the expected result from something like ``game.getPosition[0]`` (square brackets rather than parentheses).

Comment: @jasonharper yes, I have changed that

Comment: @kennytm Sure, I just edited my question with the full trace

Comment: Please add some more details about what you want `calcNextStep()` to do. In your example position is never altered, just returned. If the position needs updating please let us know how.

Answer (score 0):

By using `game.getPosition[0]` you are trying to access an array `getPosition` which belongs to game. Instead, because `getPosition` is a function you have to call it first by adding `()` to the end like this `getPosition()`. Now as `getPosition()` returns an array you can them access the first element by calling first, them access like this `getPosition()[0]`

Edit with example:

```
def calculateNextStep(game):
    actions = game.getPosition()[0] 
    return actions
```

This returns tuple:

`((3,1), 'Good')`

Comment: And If I want to assign some value to position of getPosition(), how can I do it in calculateNextStep?

Comment: Well `getPosition()` it will return an array, so you can treat it as such. If you want to set the value of the position array you should create a new function `setPosition(inArray)` which takes in a position array. So get the position array, update the position, then set it. See http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/python/3942-arrays-in-python.html for array manipulation.